# A youtube video of a pop-star

Tags: german-to-english, audio

My ability to listen to and understand spoken German is inferior to my ability to read German. So I'm watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08TkcSG6MBM&feature=player_embedded), a commercial for a TV show.

During 0:18 through 0:20, Nena says:

> Jungs, zieht euch __ an.

I've gone through it several times and I can't make out the missing word. Can someone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Jungs, zieht euch warm an
```

The meaning is not a recommendation to wear warm clothes, it is something like  `"macht Euch auf 'was gefasst"`,

You can find some discussions on it at [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/):

- [sich warm anziehen](http://dict.leo.org/forum/selectThreadByDate.php?date=20020822165909)
- [zieht euch warm an!](http://dict.leo.org/forum/selectThreadByDate.php?date=20031205120816)

There was a question for an English translation of the meaning at [wer-weiss-was.de](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme46/article6333372.html)